# Supabase database not saving new user error NextJS project

Tags: sql, next.js, vercel, supabase

I created a Profiles query that will create a new user and also a Collections query for each user created. This is my first time messing with a backend so I did my best to modify from the tutorial to my project.

This is my SQL query to create the Cards query that will be necessary for the Collections query.

```
create table cards (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null,
  description text,
  image_url text
);
```

And this is my Profiles query that also creates the Collection.

```
-- Create a table for public profiles
create table profiles (
  id uuid references auth.users not null primary key,
  updated_at timestamp with time zone,
  avatar_url text
);

-- Create a table for the user's collection
create table user_collections (
  id uuid primary key,
  user_id uuid references profiles (id) not null,
  card_id integer not null,
  constraint card_id_fk foreign key (card_id) references cards (id),
  constraint user_id_fk foreign key (user_id) references profiles (id)
);

-- Set up Row Level Security (RLS)
-- See https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security for more details.
alter table profiles
  enable row level security;

create policy "Users can insert their own profile." on profiles
  for insert with check (true);

create policy "Users can update own profile." on profiles
  for update using (auth.uid() = id);

create policy "Users can select their own collections." on user_collections
  for select using (auth.uid() = user_id);

create policy "Users can insert into their own collections." on user_collections
  for insert with check (auth.uid() = user_id);

create policy "Users can update their own collections." on user_collections
  for update using (auth.uid() = user_id);

create policy "Users cannot delete their collections." on user_collections
  for delete using (auth.uid() = user_id);


-- This trigger automatically creates a profile entry when a new user signs up via Supabase Auth.
-- See https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data#using-triggers for more details.
create function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into public.profiles (id, avatar_url)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'avatar_url');
  -- Create a table for the user's collection
  execute format('create table %I (id uuid primary key, user_id uuid references profiles (id) not null, card_id integer not null, constraint card_id_fk foreign key (card_id) references cards (id), constraint user_id_fk foreign key (user_id) references profiles (id));', new.id || '_collection');
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();

-- Set up Storage!
insert into storage.buckets (id, name)
  values ('avatars', 'avatars');

-- Set up access controls for storage.
-- See https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage#policy-examples for more details.
create policy "Avatar images are publicly accessible." on storage.objects
  for select using (bucket_id = 'avatars');

create policy "Anyone can upload an avatar." on storage.objects
  for insert with check (bucket_id = 'avatars');

create policy "Anyone can update their own avatar." on storage.objects
  for update using ( auth.uid() = owner ) with check (bucket_id = 'avatars');
```

I think the issue might be in executing the Collections query but I'm not sure. If possible I can have creating the Collections in a separate query, but I did want one to be created with each new user without the ability to delete it.